# Store xquery result as json

Tags: json, serialization, exist-db

I'm using eXist-db 4.7.0 and i want to store the result of a XQuery as JSON.
Currently, i've got a XQuery that returns JSON using the serialisation options:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare namespace json = "http://www.json.org";
declare option output:method "json";
declare option output:media-type "application/json";

let $result as node() := element root {
    attribute json:array {"yes"},
    element data {
        attribute at1 {"1"},
        attribute at2 {"1"},
        element data1 {
            "test3"
        }
    }
}

return
    $result
```

whichs returns nice JSON content:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "at1": "1",
            "at2": "1",
            "data1": "test3"
        }
    }
]
```

Now i want to store the resulting JSON directly into the DB. I've tried to replace the `return $result` clause by

```
return
    xmldb:store (
        '/db/services',
        'test1.json',
        $result
    )
```

but this stores the result as

```
<root xmlns:json="http://www.json.org" json:array="yes">
    <data at1="1" at2="1">
        <data1>test3</data1>
    </data>
</root>
```

Setting the MIME type to `application/json` didn't change anything:

```
return xmldb:store(
    '/db/services',
    'test1.json',
    $result,
    'application/json'
)
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer deleted by its owner (i will gladly accept it as soon as it's restored) led me on the right way: calling **[`fn:serialize()`](http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.fn.FnModule&details=true#serialize.1)** on the `$result` solved the issue (see also [the eXist-db blog on XQuery 3.1 support](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/XQuery31)).

So, modifying the return clause as follows solved the issue:

```
return
    xmldb:store(
    '/db/services',
    'test1.json',
    serialize($result, map { 'method':'json'})
)
```